# How can I find an answer I posted today that is not in my list of answers?

Tags: support

I posted an answer earlier today and wanted to review it again, because I had another idea. However it is not in my list of answers. Can it be that the question was closed/deleted because of it’s poor wording? How could I still locate it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to the [list of answers in your profile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=answers). At the bottom, there's a link 'recently deleted answers':

[image]

That will lead you to a page which "shows answers you posted that were deleted in the last 60 days. This includes answers to questions that were deleted."

Normally, you'll need 10k reputation to see deleted posts, but an exception is made for your own posts and for deleted questions you wrote an answer to.

Comment: Thanks Glorfindel, but also there I cannot find the question. The question was asking how to reproduce a special item marking from Microsoft Word. It had little text and only two images of the expected result. Maybe it is only closed, not deleted? Any other ideas how to locate my answer?

Comment: Then you probably didn't post it (perhaps you forgot to click the 'Submit' button?). It will be hard to find it back. Final thought: perhaps it was on another site than TeX.SE?

Comment: @TobiBS: From your description "special item marking from Microsoft Word [...] little text [...] two images of the expected result", I was reminded of this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/560434/134144 Probably this is the one you are searching? (However, there is no answer of you there.)

Comment: @leandriis Thanks, it is exactly this question and it had no answer of me until some minues ago.

Comment: Therefore shame on me, @Glorfindel was right, that I never posted the answer, but luckily I found the open tab, that still had it.